# style.background binding not working in ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

I am trying to save the color of based on the coming color value from an array but it isn't working my code us

```
 <ion-option *ngFor="let color of details.colors"   [value]="color" >{{color}} <div style="width: 10px; height:10px" [style.background]="color" ></div></ion-option>
```

I am getting color value but its not changing the background color of div.

Answer (score 0):

You have just added `style.background`, Replace it with `style.backgroundColor` like below :

```html
<ion-option *ngFor="let color of details.colors"   [value]="color" >{{color}} <div style="width: 10px; height:10px" [style.backgroundColor]="color" ></div></ion-option>
```

Comment: I have Tried this but its still not working @kishan